# A limit of conjugate representations in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{GL}$Let $G$ be a finitely presented group with generators $g_1,\dotsc, g_k$. Suppose we have a family of representations $\rho_t:G\to \GL(n,\mathbb C)$ with $t\in [0,1]$ smoothly dependent on $t$. Suppose that  for any $t\in [0,1]$ and $i\in\{1,\dotsc,k\}$, $\rho_t(g_i)$ is diagonalisable, and for $t>0$ all representations $\rho_t$ are conjugate.

**Question.** Is it true that $\rho_0$ is conjugate to $\rho_t$ for $t>0$?

(**PS** *Yves gave a counter-example in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376770/a-limit-of-conjugate-representations-in-mathrmgln-mathbb-c#comment955517_376770)*.)

Is the answer positive, if we additionally ask $\rho_t(G)\subset \GL(n,\mathbb C)$ to be conjugate to a subgroup of $\operatorname U(n)\subset \GL(n,\mathbb C)$ for all $t$?

Comment: I like this problem and the representation-theoretic language but it may be worth noting that (as is seen by pulling back to $\mathbb Z^k$, say) it is 'just' a question about simultaneous conjugacy of limits of $k$-tuples of diagonalisable matrices.  Whether that makes it seem easier or harder I don't know ….

Comment: Excuse me, pulling back to the free group $F_k = \mathbb Z^{\mathop* k}$, [not $\mathbb Z^k$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376770/a-limit-of-conjugate-representations-in-gln-mathbb-c#comment955492_376770).

Comment: No, just take $k=2$ and $\rho_t(g_1)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & t \\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, $\rho_t(g_2)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, say for $G=D_\infty$ or $F_2$. (These are not faithful but it's trivial to change this to a faithful example.)

Comment: Yves, thanks! But what about the case when all these representations are unitary? (I really want a positive answer... :) )

Comment: Sorry, I meant unitarisable (i.e. I mean exactly what is asked in the second part of the question). These representation don't need to lie in $U(n)$, but they are conjugate to subgroups in $U(n)$

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look. On the other hand, if you know where it is located in the book (and how this statement is formulated - I guess this can be formulated in a not quite recognisable way...), please do write it up as an answer to the question.

Comment: It might be termed in terms of traces (= characters). I'm not sure what are the optimal assumptions ensuring that finite-dimensional representations with the same character are conjugate.

Comment: I edited in a link to @YCor's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376770/a-limit-of-conjugate-representations-in-mathrmgln-mathbb-c#comment955517_376770).  In the meantime, a TeX note:  `\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}` is redundant; `\DeclareMathOperator\cs{op}` is equivalent (I think …) to `\newcommand\cs{\operatorname{op}}`, so you only need `\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is proven in Lemma 1.25 of the book "Varieties of representations" by Lubotzky and Magid (Memoirs of AMS, vol. 336, 1985) that each $GL(n,{\mathbb C})$-conjugation orbit of a semisimple representation $\rho\in R_n={\mathrm Hom}(\Gamma, GL(n, {\mathbb C}))$ is Zariski-closed in $R_n$. If a representation is unitarizable, then it is completely reducible, i.e. [semisimple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_representation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20specifically%20in%20representation%20theory%2C%20a%20semisimple,example%20of%20the%20general%20mathematical%20notion%20of%20semisimplicity.). Thus, you get the property you are after. Note that you do not need finite presentability of $\Gamma$, only finite generation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks indeed like this answers the question.

Comment: @aglearner, don't forget to accept!

Comment: Sure Loren, I never forget :) , just want to stare in the book for a bit longer